# Ansible error with auto provision Mikrotik router

Tags: ansible, automation, mikrotik, routeros

I have a problem that I cannot understand how to solve ...

From my ansible central machine I have written a routine for Mikrotik, to execute a series of configuration commands and thus auto provision my RBs, but it returns the following error, and I just don't know how to pass the OS detection configuration to me asks, do I have to pass it to it as a variable in the Ansible configuration file? About Ansible's own script? I just couldn't find much info about it.

Error :

```
fatal: [10.0.21.10]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unable to automatically determine host network os. Please manually configure ansible_network_os value for this host"}
```

If someone has already worked on Ansible + Mikrotik automation I would really appreciate the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inventory variable `ansible_network_os` should be set to `routeros` according to the [Ansible network platform documentation](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/docs/docsite/rst/network/user_guide/platform_index.rst#settings-by-platform).

Comment: Okay, I just realized how I have to put the argument into Ansible's inventory! Thank you!